# Looping an Array to store values that use the previous element

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I Am trying to loop an array so that it will store a number based on the equation. Where the next element is used in the equation. (sorry if that doesn't explain it too well) But here is an example. A=10-1, B=A-1, C=B-1. Hope that clears it up bit.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
                       (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int tryAgain =1;
    double[]arrayYear = new double[41];
    System.out.println("DECLINING ATTENDANCE");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    System.out.println("Attendance has been decreasing steadily at weekly religious services from\n1985. This program will dislpay the percentage of the Canadian population that\nattends a weekly religious service, from any year from 1985-2025.");
    for (int i = 0; i <=40; i ++){
        arrayYear[i] = 30-0.45;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrayYear[i] = 30 - 0.45 * i;
```

Or, for more accuracy:

```
arrayYear[i] = 30 - 45 * i / 100.0;
```

Comment: Wow Thanks im surprised something so simple stumped me. Guess i thought it would have been more complicated so i overlooked the easy stuff

Comment: umm.. I found your comment below, accumulated error, got it

Comment: @justmscs Right, 0.45 is actually parsed into the nearest binary floating-point quantity, 0.450000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125. So with `0.45 * i`, when `i == 40` (the end of the OP's loop), the skew will be multiplied by 40. With the `45 * i / 100.0` approach, the `45 * i` part is exact, so you will always have the minimum skew each time (which happens in the `/ 100.0` part).

Comment: Another question, how do you know 0.45 is actually parsed into 0.450000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125?

Comment: @justmscs `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.45));`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the previous value by using `arrayYear[i-1]`. Be careful though because if you start at `i = 0`, you will ask for element `-1` in the array which doesn't exist. You can circumvent that by setting the first value to `9` and starting at `i = 1`:

```
arrayYear[0] = 9;

for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
    arrayYear[i] = arrayYear[i-1]-1;
```

Comment: For the case of decreasing by 1 each time, your solution is fine. For the OP's other example of decreasing by 0.45 each time (a number that does not exist in binary floating point, only in approximation), the error will accumulate each iteration and after enough iterations, the number will be quite skewed. :-) (This is why I posted the `45 * i / 100.0` solution.)

Comment: Well I just answered OP's question, which was how to access the previous element of the array! Also I went with his example "But here is an example. A=10-1, B=A-1, C=B-1". But anyways, you are correct: accessing the previous element is unnecessary and can lead to errors in the calculation.